# How can I count the frequency of words without using Collections?

Tags: java

**Results**

```
0: Bear
1: Car
2: Bear
3: Cat
4: Car
5: Dog
6: Bear
---Frequency---
Bear : 1
Car : 1
null : 1
Cat : 1
null : 1
Dog : 1
null : 1
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Bear Car Bear Cat Car Dog Bear";
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
        String word[] = new String[10];
        String unique[] = new String[10];
        String w;

        int count = -1;

        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            count++;
            w = str.nextToken();
            word[count] = w;

            System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);

        }

        System.out.println("---Frequency---");

        // create unique words
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

            if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {
                unique[i] = word[i];
            }
        }

        // measuring frequency
        int[] measure = new int[10];

        for (int z = 0; z < 7; z++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[z])) {
                measure[z] += 1;
                System.out.println(unique[z] + " : " + measure[z]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is an array not a collection?

Comment: Why would you want to use this approach instead of using `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: I made the edit to my question. I want to, for the sake of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your current code:

1. You're using `Collection` interface explicitly. This is done every time you call `Arrays#asList(...)`. You're not fulfilling with your main requirement.
2. You should maintain a counter for the elements in all your arrays. In this case, you could use the same variable to hold the size of both `unique` and `measure` arrays.
3. Your algorithm to fill `unique` is wrong. You should only add the word **once** (since it must be unique).
4. You should add the counter for `measure` only once per every `String` in `unique` array.

This code takes into account all these recommendations.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ThirteenthMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Bear Car Bear Cat Car Dog Bear";
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
        String word[] = new String[10];
        String unique[] = new String[10];
        // reading the words to analyze
        int wordSize = 0;
        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String w = str.nextToken();
            word[wordSize] = w;
            System.out.println(wordSize + ": " + word[wordSize]);
            wordSize++;
        }
        System.out.println("---Frequency---");
        // create unique words
        int uniqueWordSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < wordSize; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < uniqueWordSize; j++) {
                if (word[i].equals(unique[j])) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                unique[uniqueWordSize++] = word[i];
            }
        }
        // measuring frequency
        int[] measure = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueWordSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < wordSize; j++) {
                if (unique[i].equals(word[j])) {
                    measure[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        //printing results
        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueWordSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(unique[i] + " : " + measure[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
0: Bear
1: Car
2: Bear
3: Cat
4: Car
5: Dog
6: Bear
---Frequency---
Bear : 3
Car : 2
Cat : 1
Dog : 1
```

Comment: Hey Luiggi, thanks for your answer. I edited my code after having realized (inspired from your answer) that I have infamously missed the nested loops towards the end. I just had to make a few lines of changes to my existing code to make it fully work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Luiggi for the inspiration . Here is my solution, realizing I had missed something very important. The nested loops. It is just a few lines of editing to my existing code. I would love you all to look at Luiggi's code as it is more verbose (hehe).

**Result**

```
0: Bear
1: Car
2: Bear
3: Cat
4: Car
5: Dog
6: Bear
---Frequency---
Bear : 3
Car : 2
Cat : 1
Dog : 1
```

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Bear Car Bear Cat Car Dog Bear";
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
        String word[] = new String[10];
        String unique[] = new String[10];
        String w;

        int count = -1;

        while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            count++;
            w = str.nextToken();
            word[count] = w;

            System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);

        }

        System.out.println("---Frequency---");

        // create unique words
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

            if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {

                unique[i] = word[i];
            }

        }

        // measuring frequency
        int[] measure = new int[10];

        for (int z = 0; z < 7; z++) {

            if (unique[z] != null) {

                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {

                    if (unique[z].equals(word[j])) {

                        measure[z] += 1;

                    }
                }
                System.out.println(unique[z] + " : " + measure[z]);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
String text = "Bear Car Bear Cat Car Dog Bear";
String[] allWords = text.split(" ");
String[] foundWords = new String[allWords.length];
int[] foundCount = new int[allWords.length];
int foundIndex= 0;

for (String aWord : allWords) {
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < foundIndex; j++) {
        if (foundWords[j].equals(aWord)) { //found
            foundCount[j]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j == foundIndex) { //word bot found in foundWords
        foundWords[foundIndex] = aWord;
        foundCount[foundIndex] = 1;
        foundIndex++;
    }
}

// Print result
for (int i = 0; i <foundIndex ; i++) {
    System.out.println(foundWords[i] + " : " + foundCount[i]);
}
```

The result is:

```
Bear : 3
Car : 2
Cat : 1
Dog : 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting to implement for me :)

Comment: +1, but I already edited my code after finding the bug. Check :)

Comment: Thanks, where you found a bug, in my code? If yes please let me know

Comment: Not in your code, in my code, so I answered myself. It was a loop

Comment: Minor changes, just a nested loop.

Comment: I mean , hav you updates it here. If yes I will ++ your question, if no - I can't, sorry :) BTW you can provide it as a answere.